# Accessing ng-model data in controller using angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a string containing Json data which is being generated by some another script(lets say script A). I have to access this data using ng-model. So what i tried is that i created an input field like below and attached ng-model to it.

```
`<input type="text" id="check" name="jsonName" ng-model="saveJson"></input>`
```

Now what i did is I stored the Json data into this input field using script A
 like below

```
document.getElementById("check").value = saveJson;
```

Now to access this data into angular i created a controller like

```
    angular.module('myapp').controller('formDataController', ['$scope',
    function($scope){
        $scope.saveForm = function(){
            console.log($scope.saveJson);
        }
    }
]);
```

where saveForm is a method which is called on a button click using ng-click

Now the problem is u**ntil there is any interaction** in input field the  $scope.saveJson gives an **undefiend** value.
But when i write something in input field then console.log shows json data with typed value.

Please help.

Comment: you should always set scope variable like `$scope.saveJson = saveJson` from your controller.setting scope variable outside angular will not run the digest cycle , scope variable will not update..you need to do `$scope.$apply()` to get updated value of all scope variables

Comment: how should i use this $scope.$apply()

Comment: you could use `if(!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply()` but this is bad code in terms of angular.'

Comment: I used but its not working

Comment: you should do it before accessing $scope, inside controller

Comment: I am using this before saveForm function in controller

Comment: forget everything do `$scope.saveJson = saveJson;` inside controller

Answer (score 3):

Well you need to define $scope.saveJson as property within your controller

```
angular.module('myapp').controller('formDataController', ['$scope',
function($scope){
$scope.saveJson = "something";    
$scope.saveForm = function(){
        console.log($scope.saveJson);
    }
}
]);
```